# Cannot perform system upgrade with pacman on Arch

Tags: upgrade, pacman

for a couple of days I cannot upgrade my Arch system after I run `sudo pacman -Syu` I'm receiving this error:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: libquicktime: installing libx264 (2:152.20171224-1.0) breaks dependency 'libx264.so=148-32'
```

If I run `sudo pacman -S libx264` I get this:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: ffmpeg: installing libx264 (2:152.20171224-1.0) breaks dependency 'libx264.so=148-32'
:: ffmpeg2.8: installing libx264 (2:152.20171224-1.0) breaks dependency 'libx264.so=148-32'
:: libquicktime: installing libx264 (2:152.20171224-1.0) breaks dependency 'libx264.so=148-32'
```

UPDATE

Finally I managed to perform an upgrade by putting `libx264` *on hold* as stated on my comment below but still cannot get it why even `--force` option won't overwrite this package.

Comment: try running `-Syyu` instead of `-Syu` to make sure your package db is up-to-date.

Comment: `-Syyu` ends up with the same results as `-Syu`

Comment: are you on `amd64` or another architecture?  have you tried a different mirror?

Comment: no I'm still running i686 using archlinux32 repos which are still maintained

Comment: well I happened to partially upgrade what I did I ignored `libx264` package in `pacman.conf` and upgrade finally moved forward and after that I've noticed that `libx264` conflicts with `libx264-10bit` that's the one that wants to replace `libx264` I assume, I even tried to reinstall it with `--force` option but it still won't go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been some time since I posted this question but anyways I found another solution with `pacman`

```
sudo pacman -Rdd libx264

sudo pacman -S libx264
```

or

```
sudo pacman -S libx265
```

Depends on what you need and then:

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

To complete full upgrade.

Basically works with any package that gets stuck.

Comment: Nice. To clarify: -Rdd performs a remove skipping all dependency checks. And then you just reinstall it to get the newer version.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this by simply **removing** ffmpeg0.10:

> yaourt -R ffmpeg0.10

(no complaints from the system doing that).
After that a complete upgrade with

> sudo pacman -Syyu

worked just fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the issue has gone on its own since today probably the issue was on Arch side

Answer (score 0):

Mb uninstall your AUR packages so you can properly upgrade. Or build using aurutils as it mb uses clean chroot builds.
After that also try:

```
pacman -Syu libx264
```

or

```
pacman -Syyu libx264 # Passing two --refresh or -y flags will force a refresh of all package lists even if they appear to be up to date.
```

This could mean that your AUR packages need an update

Comment: funny thing that I did upgrade all the packahes only `libx264` won't upgrade I stated what I did in a comment above